# Unable to read from serial port on command line

Tags: serial-port, cat, echo

I tried reading from /dev/ttyS0 on 1 terminal as root with cat:

```
cat < /dev/ttyS0
```

and sending message to the serial port from another terminal as root with echo:

```
echo -ne "hello" > /dev/ttyS0
```

But I got nothing from the cat. Can someone enlighten me to the cause of the problem?

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard or public support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL (*end-of-life*) thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is in *extended* support and only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades
https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/

Comment: Wait this site is by Canonical? I thought it is by volunteers?

Comment: It is by volunteers. However there is no point spending time on an unsupported release... Anyway, what is on the other side of the serial port you are trying to read and write? A modem, another computer?

Comment: It's an official site affiliated with Ubuntu yes, why I can use the site without logging in via Stack Exchange (ie. using my Ubuntu-ONE SSO), but it's volunteers who are here too.

Comment: Nothing is on the other side. I just ```ls /dev/```, saw ttyS0 is listed, then give it a try, but did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device `/dev/ttyS0` normally corresponds to your computer's first serial port. Nowadays, computers do not have serial ports, but some USB devices may appear at a `/dev/ttyS`***x*** port of your system. If the device was connected to your computer during boot, you can find the device name probably by running:

`journalctl -b | grep ttyS`

If the device is not connected yet, first run the command:

`journalctl -f | grep ttyS`

and then connect the device; you should see a message indicating the port number ***x***.

---

If you are trying to send data to the virtual consoles of a desktop system, first press the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> and log in to the virtual console displayed in text mode. Then run the command

`who am i`

to verify that the device you have logged in is actually `/dev/tty4` (the second word of the above command's output should be `tty4` in this case).

On the main graphical screen (which can be reached by pressing the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) open a terminal and run the command:

`echo "Hello" >/dev/tty4`

Switch back to the console using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> and see that message displayed.

Similarly run the following command on the main graphical screen:

`cat </dev/tty4`

Switch back to the console and try to enter some characters. Some of the characters will be echoed to the screen (by `bash`), some will not. The characters not echoed will be displayed on the main graphical screen as the output of the `cat` command. The reason for this is that the same device is being read by two processes (one on the text console which is `bash` and the other on the graphical screen which is the `cat` command).

---

### Note:

For a non-root user to be able to read & write to a serial port, that user needs to have read & write permission for that device. In Ubuntu, this can easily be done by adding the current user to the `dialout` group using the

`sudo addgroup _your_user_ dialout`

You may have to log out and then log back in for this change to take effect.

Comment: Does this also work if there is no actual hardware connected to /dev/ttyS0?

Comment: @ablan No. There must be some device "connected" to this port... And, if there is something extra info you need in my answer, please inform me so.